# Assign the value of custom fomatter using callback to a jqgrid column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have written a code that uses a custom formatter for a jqgrid column . The formatter is using callabck. When trying to assign the value of the this function to the formatter,I am getting undefined value whereas when putting alert I am getting correct value. Here is my code.Any help shall be appreciated.

```
var str='';
function myFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject, callback) {

var loadUrl= 'someUrl';


    $.getJSON(loadUrl, function(jsnResponse) {

        if (typeof (callback) === "function") {
            alert('within callback ' + jsnResponse.logo);
            str= '<img width="20"  src=' + jsnResponse.logo + '  />';
            callback(str);
        }

    });
```

}

For calling this function and assigning to jqgrid formatter I am using the following code

```
formatter :  function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
                                    return myFormatter
                                    (cellvalue, options, rowObject, function(str) {
                                        alert('in formatter '+str);


                                });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is a misunderstanding what is custom formatter and how it will be used. Custom formatter is already callback function which you have to define if you want use the functionality. **jqGrid calls your callback** if the property `formatter` in defined for some column and its value is a function. Because jqGrid makes the call, jqGrid specify parameters which it uses.

On the other side the second parameter (`options` parameter) of custom formatter contains some properties which can be helpful for you. For example `colModel` property (`options.colModel`) is the element of `colModel` where custom formatter are used. The following code shows what I mean

```
function myFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var myOption1 = options.colModel.formatoptions.myOption1;
    ...
}

...

colModel: [
    { name: "col1", formatoptions: { myOption1: "abc" }, formatter: myFormatter },
    { name: "col2", formatoptions: { myOption1: "xyz" }, formatter: myFormatter },
    ...
]
```

In the above way the same function `myFormatter` will be called with different `myOption1` option (`"abc"` or `"xyz"`) for different columns. You can define *any* set of options of *any type* (inclusive callback functions). If it's required you can access to rowid inside of custom formatter: you can just use `options.rowId`.